# Eloquent Join, multiple where queries, change AND to OR

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following Eloquent query:

```
    CustomerStore::restrictBasedOnSession()
        ->joinCustomerWhere([
            ["first_name", "like", "%$query%"],
            ["last_name", "like", "%$query%"],
            ["phone", "like", "%$query%"]
        ])
        ->joinAddressWhere([
            ["postcode", "like", "%$query%"]
        ])
        ->get([
            'customers.id as id',
            'customers.first_name as firstname',
            'customers.last_name as lastname',
            'customers.phone as phone',
        ]);
```

With the following scopes

```
public function scopeJoinCustomerWhere($query, $array)
{
    $query->leftJoin('customers', 'customers.id', '=', 'customer_store.customer_id');

    foreach ($array as $clause) {
        $query->orWhere('customers.' . $clause[0], $clause[1], $clause[2]);
    }

    return $query;
}

public function scopeJoinAddressWhere($query, $array)
{
    $query->leftJoin('customer_addresses', 'customer_addresses.customer_id', '=', 'customer_store.customer_id');

    foreach ($array as $clause) {
        $query->orWhere('customer_addresses.' . $clause[0], $clause[1], $clause[2]);
    }

    return $query;
}


public function scopeRestrictBasedOnSession($query)
{
    return $query->where('store_id', '=', config('app.config.id'));
}
```

My issue is that when I dump out my query for the above Eloquent query, my SQL is

**select `customers`.`id` as `id`, `customers`.`first_name` as `firstname`, `customers`.`last_name` as `lastname`, `customers`.`phone` as `phone`**

**from `customer_store`
    left join `customers` on `customers`.`id` = `customer_store`.`customer_id`
    left join `customer_addresses` on `customer_addresses`.`customer_id` = `customer_store`.`customer_id`**

**where 
    `store_id` = 1 and
    (`customers`.`first_name` like '%e%' or `customers`.`last_name` like '%e%' or `customers`.`phone` like '%e%') AND (`customer_addresses`.`postcode` like '%e%') AND
    `customer_store`.`deleted_at` is null**

I am trying to change

**where 
    `store_id` = 1 and
    (`customers`.`first_name` like '%e%' or `customers`.`last_name` like '%e%' or `customers`.`phone` like '%e%') AND (`customer_addresses`.`postcode` like '%e%') AND
    `customer_store`.`deleted_at` is null**

to

**where 
    `store_id` = 1 and
    (`customers`.`first_name` like '%e%' or `customers`.`last_name` like '%e%' or `customers`.`phone` like '%e%') or (`customer_addresses`.`postcode` like '%e%') OR
    `customer_store`.`deleted_at` is null**

Specifically, when I do a where across multiple tables, I don't want the condition between the tables to be `AND`, I need it to be `OR`.

If anybody has any advice I would appreciate it <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to have all where clause in same scope rather than creating multiple scope methods.

Eloquent query will group clauses within each scope method. So, every scope method is distinct and Eloquent append clauses in 'AND'.

Something like this:

```
public function scopeJoinRelationWhere($query, $array)
{
    $query->leftJoin('customer_addresses', 'customer_addresses.customer_id', '=', 'customer_store.customer_id');

    $query->leftJoin('customers', 'customer.id', '=', 'customer_store.customer_id');

    foreach ($array['addresses'] as $clause) {
        $query->orWhere('customer_addresses.' . $clause[0], $clause[1], $clause[2]);
    }

    foreach ($array['customers'] as $clause) {
        $query->orWhere('customers.' . $clause[0], $clause[1], $clause[2]);
    }

    return $query;
}
```